# I have mysql where i want to check a value whether it in an array if there values = x and if not value = y

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the sample :

```
SELECT toys.name, model.name
FROM model, toys

LEFT JOIN model
ON toys.model = model.name

WHERE model.name IN (robots,cops,trucks) toys.price = 100 or toys.price = 10
```

If I found toys in the list I want the toys.price = 100 else toys.price = 10

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? I'm not sure I understand  your question

Comment: You have an error in your query, in your where clause. Can you please give us the correct query?

Comment: if there are toys with price over 100, retrieve toys with price of 100. Else, retrieve toys with price 10. Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: there are two tables model and toys , i want to sort the toys based on the toys price. If I find the any toy model IN (trucks, cops, ) the price will be 100. if not the toy price = 10. there are only two prices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with this query:

```
SELECT `toys`.`name`, `model`.`name`, IF (`model`.`name` IN ('robots', 'cops', 'truck'), 100, 10) AS price
FROM `toys`

LEFT JOIN `model`
ON `toys`.`model` = `model`.`name`
```

First of all: I used quotes and backticks in the query.
[You can read the reason on this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)
Always use them!

Second of all: no need to have 2 tables in the `from`, if you're joining them.

Third of all: the solution you want, can be solved with the [if](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function:
 If the model name is one if these three, the price will be 100, otherwise it will be 10.

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve it by using **bracket** and **OR**. And you have to use quotes in your model name as they are string. Here is a sample query

```
SELECT toys.name, model.name
FROM toys
LEFT JOIN model
ON toys.model = model.name
WHERE (model.name IN ('robots','cops','trucks') AND toys.price = 100) OR toys.price = 10
```